# Firebase Realtime Database error when saving data with data list structure

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Please help, I had problem when trying to save the value in my object where the object is list type, below the model

```
public class Bill implements Serializable, Comparable<Bill> {
    private List<Users> usersList; 
}
```

The error screenshot
[image]

My saving code

```
mDatabase
.child(Global.FD_TABLE_CREATE_BILL+Global.GLOBAL_DB_PARAMETER+users.getTenant().getId())
.child(bill.getBillID()).setValue(bill)
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run (){
                //do something here
    }
})
.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

The error coming when try to update object value usersList for second times (the first time update working fine without any problem)

Seems realtime database keep doing update the userList when the length of the list is different or may the value is changed.

Below is the completed method and code.

```
public void validatePaymentBeforeUpdateUserSelectedForBill(final Context context,final FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance,final DatabaseReference mDatabase,final List<String> lastSelectedUser,final Bill bill,final List<Users> usersList,final Users users,
                                                           final HomeCollaborationModel homeCollaborationModel,
                                                           final List<MasterPayment> masterPayment,final List<BankList> masterBankLists,
                                                           final UserRoles userRoles,final List<PaymentMax> paymentMaxList) {
    final boolean[] failedValidation = {false};
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference dataReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child(Global.FD_TABLE_PAYMENT + Global.GLOBAL_DB_PARAMETER + users.getTenant().getId());
    final boolean[] gotResult = new boolean[1];
    gotResult[0] = false;
    final Query queryData;
    queryData = dataReference.orderByChild("billID").equalTo(bill.getBillID());
    final ValueEventListener dataFetchEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get user information
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                DatabaseReference mDatabaseLocal = mDatabase;
                List<PaymentConfirmation> paymentConfirmationList = new ArrayList<PaymentConfirmation>();
                gotResult[0] = true;
                for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    PaymentConfirmation bill = messageSnapshot.getValue(PaymentConfirmation.class);
                    if (bill != null) {
                        paymentConfirmationList.add(bill);
                    }
                }
                if (paymentConfirmationList.size() > 0){
                    List<Users> userses = new ArrayList<Users>();
                    for (int i =0;i < getSelectedStrings().size(); i++){
                        for (int j =0; j < usersList.size(); j ++){
                            String userListValue = usersList.get(j).getName()+" -> "+usersList.get(j).getTenant().getUniqueData();
                            if (getSelectedStrings().get(i).toString().trim().equals(userListValue.trim())){
                                userses.add(usersList.get(j));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    for (PaymentConfirmation paymentConfirmation : paymentConfirmationList){
                        boolean isExistOnUserSelected = false;
                        for (Users usersSelected: userses){
                            if (paymentConfirmation.getCreatedBy().getId().equals(usersSelected.getId())){
                                isExistOnUserSelected = true;
                                break;
                            }else{
                                isExistOnUserSelected = false;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!isExistOnUserSelected){
                            for (Users userData: usersList){
                                if (paymentConfirmation.getCreatedBy().getId().equals(userData.getId())){
                                    userses.add(userData);
                                    break;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(userses.size() > 0){
                        bill.setUsersList(userses);
                    }
                    mDatabase.child(Global.FD_TABLE_CREATE_BILL+Global.GLOBAL_DB_PARAMETER+users.getTenant().getId())
                            .child(bill.getBillID()).setValue(bill)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run (){
                                            String[] serializablesName = {"Users","HomeCollaborationModel","MasterPayment","userRoles","openedBy","callbackBillID","BankList","PaymentMaxList"};
                                            Serializable[] serializables = {users,homeCollaborationModel, (Serializable) masterPayment,userRoles,2,bill.getBillID(),(Serializable) masterBankLists, (Serializable) paymentMaxList};
                                            IntentController.globalIntent(context, BillContainer.class, serializablesName, serializables,0,true, true);

                                        }

                                    }, Global.SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT);
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            });
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };
    queryData.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(dataFetchEventListener);
}
```

Comment: Are you using the above code in a loop?

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo, absolutely no. I didn’t put the code inside the looping logic.

Comment: @AlexMamo, I just adding the completed code and method when I tried update the value in RD with list type